# Cómo puedo obtener el id de un botón después de hacer clic

Tags: javascript

tengo una columna con diferentes botones y quiero obtener el id después de hacer clic al botón(creado desde javascript), para relacionarlo con un email del JSON.
Mi código es este:

Código del botón:

```
var boton = document.createElement("button");
        boton.setAttribute("id",data.people.contact_info.email)
        boton.textContent = "more info";
        boton.addEventListener("click", function () {

            $('#myModal').modal('show'); // abrir
            $('#myModal').modal('hide'); // cerrar
            fillModal()
        });

function fillModal(){

    var nameM = document.getElementsByName("button")[0]; 

    for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) { 

        if ( id == email ) { 

           console.log(email);
    };
```

el id dentro del if es el que necesito obtener.

Se que necesito esta parte de código, pero no se como implementarla al mío.

```
event.srcElement.id;
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes obtener el id usando `this.id` asi:

```js
var boton = document.createElement("button");
boton.setAttribute("id","test")
boton.textContent = "more info";
boton.addEventListener("click", function () {               
    console.log(this.id);
});
document.body.append(boton);
```